# setTimeout alternative in protractor

Tags: javascript, selenium, protractor, settimeout

Just started working on a functional test repo that uses protractor and tests an angular 4 app. Throughout the tests we're wrapping almost every action in a setTimeout and surely theres a better way. Here's a small example. Is there a config option somewhere or something that waits for page and network calls to finish?

```
it('do something', function (done) {
    setTimeout(() => {
        var adminBtn = element(by.id('adminBtn'));
        adminBtn.click();
        setTimeout(() => {
            var payloadsBtn = element(by.id('payloadsBtn'));
            payloadsBtn.click();
            setTimeout(() => {
                expect(browser.getCurrentUrl()).toMatch(conf.web + "/payloads");
                done();
            }, 3000)
        }, 2000)
    }, 4000)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In short, yes.

```
exports.config = {    
    allScriptsTimeout: 60000,
    getPageTimeout: 30000,
    jasmineNodeOpts: {
        defaultTimeoutInterval: 124000
    }
};
```

More information here:
https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/timeouts.md

Comment: They're not asking about these kinds of timeouts, they're asking about set timeouts. Asynchronous functions that wait a specified amount of time before executing the code there-in.